# Why cant we use rank() analytic function to delete duplicates in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an emp table with the following records in it.

```
    create table emp(
    EMPNO  integer,
    EMPNAME varchar2(20),
    SALARY  number);

select * from emp;

empno empname  salary
10    bill     2000
11    bill     2000
12    mark     3000
12    mark     3000
12    mark     3000
12    philip   3000
12    john     3000
13    tom      4000
14    tom      4000
14    jerry    5000
14    matt     5000
15    susan    5000
```

To delete duplicates i have been using the rownum() function along with partition by and order by clause with the query as follows:

```
delete from emp where rowid in
(
select rid from
(
select rowid rid,
row_number() over(partition by empno order by empno) rn
from emp
)
where rn > 1
);
--6 rows deleted
```

The query deletes all the employee records with duplicate empno's and the result looks somethin like this:

```
empno empname  salary
10    bill     2000
11    bill     2000
12    mark     3000
13    tom      4000
14    tom      4000
15    susan    5000
```

When i use the inner query to fetch the rownumbers for all the results in the table it gives me the following result:

```
select rowid as rid,empno,empname,
row_number() over(partition by empno order by empno) rn
from emp;

rowid                         rownumber
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAA  10  bill    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAB  11  bill    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAE  12  mark    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAD  12  mark    2
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAC  12  mark    3
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAF  12  philip  4
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAG  12  john    5
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAH  13  tom     1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAI  14  tom     1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAJ  14  jerry   2
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAK  14  matt    3
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAL  15  susan   1
```

But when i use rank() in place of the rownumber() function it gives me the following result:

```
select rowid as rid,empno,empname,
rank() over(partition by empno order by empno) rn
from emp;

rowid                          rank
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAA  10  bill    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAB  11  bill    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAE  12  mark    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAD  12  mark    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAC  12  mark    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAF  12  philip  1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAG  12  john    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAH  13  tom     1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAI  14  tom     1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAJ  14  jerry   1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAK  14  matt    1
AACDJUAAPAAGLlTAAL  15  susan   1
```

So my question here is why does rank() give the same value to all the records in the table even though there are duplicate empid's?

Comment: Given your business rules, what exactly is _"a duplicate"_ : (1) same id (2) same name (3) same id _and_ same name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the way `RANK()` works. It would be rather surprising to get different `RANK` values for equal-ranking rows within the partition. In fact, the `ORDER BY` clause is the significant driver for `RANK` within a partition, but since you're using the same columns for the partitions as for the ordering, it is clear that every row ranks first within their respective partition (as they're the only value in the partition)

[See an explanation in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/), where this SQL (PostgreSQL syntax)

```
SELECT
  v,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (window) row_number,
  RANK()       OVER (window) rank,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (window) dense_rank
FROM t
WINDOW window AS (ORDER BY v)
ORDER BY v
```

... produces this output

```
+---+------------+------+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK |
+---+------------+------+------------+
| a |          1 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          2 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          3 |    1 |          1 |
| b |          4 |    4 |          2 |
| c |          5 |    5 |          3 |
| c |          6 |    5 |          3 |
| d |          7 |    7 |          4 |
| e |          8 |    8 |          5 |
+---+------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Got it but in my example why is rank() not incrementing?...I mean why is it not assigning rank as '2' for empno 11?...is it coz i am partitioning by empno?

Comment: @abhi1489 There is only one employee with empno=11, so he his at the first rank in his group.

Comment: @abhi1489, I'm sorry, I didn't catch that part from your question. Yes, `empno=11` ranks first within their partition. The way you wrote the query, in fact, everyone ranks first in their partition.

Answer (score 2):

There are three "ranking" analytic functions:  `row_number()`, `rank()`, and `dense_rank()`.

These all work very similarly.  They assign numbers, in order, to rows within a group.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause.  The ordering is defined by the `order by` clause.  The difference between the three is how they handle duplicate values.

`row_number()` *always* returns sequential numbers within the group.  When there are ties, then equal valued rows have sequential values, but they are different.

`dense_rank()` assigns sequential values with no gaps.  However, equal valued rows are given the same values.  The next value has a rank one more.

`rank()` assigns sequential values with gaps.  Equal valued rows have the same value but subsequent rows have a gap.

Here is an example:

```
value  row_number   dense_rank     rank
  a        1            1           1
  b        2            2           2
  b        3            2           2
  b        4            2           2
  c        5            3           5
  d        6            4           6
  d        7            4           6
```